# How to get gerrit link from git.push()

Tags: python, git, python-3.x

The below code pushes the change and creates gerrit, but it doesn't print the gerrit URL

```
import sh
from sh import git
git.add(file1.txt)
gitdir=git('rev-parse', '--git-dir')
sh.scp("-p","-P",port,user+"@"+ghost+":hooks/commit-msg",str(gitdir.rstrip())+"/hooks/")
git.commit(m='my commit message')
print(git.push('origin','HEAD:refs/for/master'))
```

The git.push command doesn't print anything though it successfully creates a gerrit, how to get the gerrit link after it pushes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo=git.push('origin','HEAD:refs/for/master')
output=foo.stderr.split() #Gerrit returns logs including the url to the standard error
```

Then you can get the url from the list `output` if the push is successful.